# PL/SQL Looping Count Issues

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm trying to create a PL/SQL Function that will count all my invoices for a specific customer (x) on or after a specific date (y) but can't seem to quite figure out the syntax. I've been working with SQL for a couple years but am completely new to PL/SQL coding and can't seem to implement my SQL code right. I think I have the right idea, but not sure how to loop to count each invoice for a specific customer. I keep getting errors for how I'm trying to use my COUNT and DISTINCT functions for I don't think I'm placing them in the right spot. All I want it to return is the number of invoices. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FTN_CountInv
(x IN INTEGER, y IN DATE)
RETURN INTEGER
AS
  v_inv_number    invoice.inv_number%type;
  v_cus_code      invoice.cus_code%type;
  v_inv_date      invoice.inv_date%type;
CURSOR v_inv_cursor IS SELECT inv_number, cus_code, inv_date FROM invoice;
BEGIN
OPEN v_inv_cursor;

WHILE v_inv_date >= y
LOOP
COUNT (v_inv_number)
FOR EACH DISTINCT x;
FETCH v_inv_cursor INTO v_inv_number, v_cus_code, v_inv_date;
EXIT WHEN v_inv_cursor%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE v_inv_cursor;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're newer to PL/SQL I would highly suggest using FOR LOOPS instead of cursors.  Cursors give you more flexibility but they are harder to understand and use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FTN_CountInv
(x IN INTEGER, y IN DATE)
RETURN INTEGER
AS
  v_counter integer := 0;

BEGIN
FOR c in (SELECT inv_number, cus_code, inv_date FROM invoice) LOOP
  IF c.inv_date > y THEN
    v_counter := v_counter + 1;
  END IF;
END LOOP;
RETURN v_counter
END;
```

In this case "c" becomes a way to reference to every column return by the SQL select.  "c" is then a variable containing the values for the row which change over each iteration of the loop.

Likely a simpler solution if you know SQL the best is to get the count you want using SQL and pass it into a variable you return.  See:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FTN_CountInv
(x IN INTEGER, y IN DATE)
RETURN INTEGER
AS
  v_inv_count integer;

BEGIN
SELECT count(*)
  INTO v_inv_count
  FROM invoice
 WHERE inv_date > y;

RETURN v_inv_count;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the use of cursors is defiantly what has been causing a lot of confusion. This really simplifies it.